# Is it possible to setup an OpenVPN server on Ubuntu 20.04 while it is connected to a private WLAN network (with DHCP)?

Tags: server, wireless, openvpn, dhcp

I am newbie in Ubuntu server 20.04. I have installed Ubuntu server 20.04 on a HP laptop (with a broken ethernet interface then I have to use only wifi) and I want to set up an OpenVPN service on it. The laptop is connected to a wireless network with private IP address getting the address via DHCP (on modem). I will initiate a VPN connection to this computer in the same WLAN (I am just practicing and trying some services).

```
me@me:~$ ip route list default
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.164 metric 600
```

I am wondering if it is possible to setup an OpenVPN service on Ubuntu under the aforementioned connectivity specifications?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to set up a VPN on a server that's connected via only Wi-Fi, but the speed and ping **will** jitter because of possible unreliable connection.

If you need any further assistance, you should ask a separate question.